# Parsing XML file times out

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem while parsing an XML File of 1986 lines .. it gives me execution timeout!!

here is my code:

```
$XML_File = simplexml_load_file("EXTERNAL URL");

$projects = $XML_File->channel->item;
$i = 0;
while($projects)
{
    $title = $projects[$i]->title;
    $link = $projects[$i]->link;
    $description = $projects[$i]->description;
    $category = $projects[$i]->category;
    $i++;
}
```

When I run it, it times out after 30 secs, without returning any result!!

When I changed the while to a for loop .. with a max of 4 it worked fine .. Is there a way to parse a big file?? Or shall I move to creating a desktop application??

Comment: depending on the server you might try to use `ini_set()` and extend execution time `ini_set('max_execution_time', 180)`. You can also first get the file and save it on the disc and parsing it from there, this would save few seconds of retrieving from the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$XML_File = simplexml_load_file("EXTERNAL URL"); 

$projects = $XML_File->channel->item; 
$i = 0; 
while($projects) 
{ 
    $title = $projects[$i]->title; 
    $link = $projects[$i]->link; 
    $description = $projects[$i]->description; 
    $category = $projects[$i]->category; 
    $i++; 
}
```

I don't think this is ever going to finish. You're just checking to see if `$projects` exists.

Maybe something like this will work:

```
while(isset($projects[$i]))
....
```

Comment: This actually worked for me!! Thanks .. 
I've added a execution time code that I googled for and that was the result.

This page was created in 0.221807956696 seconds